# SQLITE Select results into a string

Tags: sqlite, select

I am looking for a method to return the results of an SQLite query as a single string for use in an internal trigger.

Something like Python's `'somestring'.join()` method.

```
Table: foo
id    |    name
1     |     "foo"
2     |     "bar"
3     |     "bro"
```

Then a select statement:

```
MAGIC_STRING_CONCAT_FUNCTION(SELECT id FROM foo,",");
```

To return
    "1,2,3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `group_concat` function:

```
group_concat((SELECT id FROM foo), ",");
```

The following is [the description of the function `group_concat` from the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

> `group_concat(X)` `group_concat(X,Y)`
>
> The `group_concat()` function returns a string which is the
>   concatenation of all non-NULL values of `X`. If parameter `Y` is present
>   then it is used as the separator between instances of `X`. A comma (",")
>   is used as the separator if `Y` is omitted. The order of the
>   concatenated elements is arbitrary.