# Ordering single line array by count in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-concat

I've been trying to understand SQLite's [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) function. I have a simple query that lists the values in the section column in my table, orderered by how often they occur (most frequent first):

```sql
SELECT section
FROM analytics_analyticevent
GROUP BY section
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

> section
>   2
>   1
>   10
>   0
>   12
>   8
>   3
>   9
>   7
>   5
>   6
>   4
>   13
>   11

I would like the results to be presented as a comma-separated list so that I can cut and paste them into an array in a Python script. I would expect the following to do the trick (c.f. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28259067/575530)):

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(section, ', ')
FROM analytics_analyticevent
GROUP BY section
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

However, the results of that query do not seem to be grouped in the way I would expect, there are multiple occurences of each section.

[image: DBVisualizer screenshot showing lengthy array]

What SQL should I be writing to replicate the first query but with the results presented as a comma-separated list on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need two levels of aggregation for this. First aggregate by `section` and count how many rows there are in each group, sort, and then generate the csv string:

```
select group_concat(section, ',')
from (
    select section
    from analytics_analyticevent
    group by section
    order by count(*) desc
) t
```